# Запрос на получение данных за последнюю дату

Tags: sql

Дана таблица:
Дата, ФИО, Вес

Нужно взять Вес каждого ФИО за последнюю Дату.
Как это реализовать с помощью SQL?

У каждого ФИО замер Веса происходит в разное время. Например: (09.04.18; Иванов; 61), (16.04.18; Иванов; 60), (10.04.18; Петров; 70), (15.04.18: Петров; 71).

В этом случае нужно взять данные: (16.04.18; Иванов; 60) и (15.04.18: Петров; 71).

Comment: `select ФИО, Вес from таблица where Дата = <последнюю Дату>`

Comment: чувствуете? с вопросом Вы не уложились в две строчки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Дата, ФИО, Вес
FROM таблица 
WHERE (Дата, ФИО) IN (SELECT MAX(Дата), ФИО
                      FROM таблица 
                      GROUP BY ФИО)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает.